# The Dropzone is not working after Jquery .load() execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, load, dropzone.js

Hi can you help me to make a solution about my problem?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
        $('#sample').load('sample.html')
});
```

after the script execute and the sample.html is now loaded where my...

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>
```

is located the dropzone js is not working.

Please help me about this issue . I can't figured how to make a solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: is the `dropzone` form is loaded via the `load()` command

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about it? is your JS is not working or CSS file is not picked up?

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes the `dropzone` form is loaded via `load()`

Comment: @FahizMohamed The `dropzone.js` is not working

Answer (score 11):

You need to tell dropzone to reparse the document. If you using jquery.load method 
Also only use Dropzone.discover method after uploader is fully loaded.

```
$('#sample').load('sample.html', function() {
  Dropzone.discover();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the $.getScript method to load the JS file.. [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$.getScript("yourJsPath", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
   console.log('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: Ravi I've used that method already but still, the `dropzone.js` won't work