# How to get file by Dropzone and send it by AJAX Put request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm using  [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to select files for uploading.

Can I get file instance and send it by ajax put request?

For example:

```
$.put = function (url, data) {
         return $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'PUT',                    
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: data // Where is data avaliable in dropzone as data-binary, not as object with file's params?                   
            });
        }
```

Comment: perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016527/dropzone-js-and-ajax